# Spring-batch to spring task in Spring cloud data flow

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-cloud-task

I'm new to spring-batch and spring cloud data flow. 
I modified the sample quickstart project for the spring-batch and it now writes on a local MSSQL database: it works fine when I run it using java -jar.
I now tried to deploy it to a local instance of Spring Cloud Data Flow, imported it as a Task from the dashboard and tried to run: it gives me this error:

```
2017-11-15 17:54:46.109  INFO 17164 --- [           main] hello.Application                        : Starting Application v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on localmachine with PID 17164 (C:\Users\massimo.sporchia\eclipse-workspace\batch-example\target\batch-example-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by massimo.sporchia in C:\Users\MASSIM~1.SPO\AppData\Local\Temp\spring-cloud-dataflow-5975572085987003620\exampleTask-1510764882259\exampleTask-4fd22d5a-a5f0-49d5-8634-a4bbb21d2675)
2017-11-15 17:54:46.129  INFO 17164 --- [           main] hello.Application                        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-11-15 17:54:46.402  INFO 17164 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@1698c449: startup date [Wed Nov 15 17:54:46 CET 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-11-15 17:54:49.020  WARN 17164 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassEnhancer       : @Bean method ScopeConfiguration.stepScope is non-static and returns an object assignable to Spring's BeanFactoryPostProcessor interface. This will result in a failure to process annotations such as @Autowired, @Resource and @PostConstruct within the method's declaring @Configuration class. Add the 'static' modifier to this method to avoid these container lifecycle issues; see @Bean javadoc for complete details.
2017-11-15 17:54:49.066  WARN 17164 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassEnhancer       : @Bean method ScopeConfiguration.jobScope is non-static and returns an object assignable to Spring's BeanFactoryPostProcessor interface. This will result in a failure to process annotations such as @Autowired, @Resource and @PostConstruct within the method's declaring @Configuration class. Add the 'static' modifier to this method to avoid these container lifecycle issues; see @Bean javadoc for complete details.
2017-11-15 17:54:49.288  INFO 17164 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.task.batch.configuration.TaskBatchAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.task.batch.configuration.TaskBatchAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$da33614e] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-11-15 17:54:49.306  INFO 17164 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$54c3b5c2] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-11-15 17:54:49.441  INFO 17164 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.task.batch.listener.BatchEventAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.task.batch.listener.BatchEventAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$22896b51] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-11-15 17:54:49.631  WARN 17164 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'batchConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jobBuilderFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dataSources'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: org.h2.Driver
2017-11-15 17:54:49.653  INFO 17164 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-11-15 17:54:49.686 ERROR 17164 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'batchConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jobBuilderFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dataSources'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: org.h2.Driver
```

The same spring-batch uber-jar works when deployed as a Stream: what am I missing?

Comment: How are you registering `spring-batch` app in SCDF? It has to be registered as a `task` - are you? This statement is also confusing: "The same spring-batch uber-jar works when deployed as a Stream" - a batch-job cannot run as a stream. Please share the custom-app (code), app registration, stream, or task definition commands, and we would be happy to review it.

Comment: Hello @SabbyAnandan , thanks for your help.
I pushed the code to my github repository: https://github.com/MassimoSporchia/spring-batch-example . As you can see, I followed the spring-batch quickstart example and modified it to use a personal local MSSQL DB with a different table.
I registered both a task and a Stream from GUI by pointing the .jar from the target folder.
I know I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the repo.

To run a Spring Batch job in SCDF, you will have to adapt the application to Spring Cloud Task [programming model](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-task/docs/1.2.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-writing-the-code). Please use the [Spring Cloud Task](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-task/tree/master/spring-cloud-task-samples/batch-job) and [Spring Cloud Data Flow](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-samples/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_batch_file_ingest) batch-job samples as a reference.

Unless the application adapts to this model, it *will not* run in SCDF.

One other thing. A batch-job can only run as a Task in SCDF and it *cannot* be used in a Stream.